# How do i get the index of a 2D array if the user enters a number from the array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int f[5][5], k = 1, n;
    for (int p = 0; p<5; p++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Elements Of Rows: " << k << endl;
        k++;
        for (int m = 0; m<5; m++)
        {
            cin >> f[p][m];//It take's rows as input
        }
    }
    //What should i do now because i can't understand how to print the index of n element.
    cout << "Enter the number you want to search:  ";
    cin >> n;
    //What should i do after this to get the index of the number n?
}
```

This code is all good for taking rows as input but when it comes to index, everything goes horribly wrong. Searched and worked a lot but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. TIA.

Comment: Do you have any code for how you searched through the 2d array?

Comment: Mate, any feedback for any of the answers whatsoever? A comment, a vote, anything? Did none of the answers help you to achieve what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean converting 1D index to 2D index then this will do:

```
int x = n % 5;

int y = n / 5;
```

Assuming this format:

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

9 10 11 12 13

14 15 16 17 18

19 20 21 22 23

Then accessing it with:

```
int result = f[x][y];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any information about where the element could possibly be, I suggest you just do a linear search (meaning: look at every element and check if it is the one you are looking for).

The basic idea is that you do the exact same nested loop as you have already, but you do a check instead of an insert, like so:

```
...
...
cout << "Enter the number you want to search:  ";
cin >> n;

for (int p = 0; p<5; p++)
{

    for (int m = 0; m<5; m++)
    {
        if (f[p][m]==n){
          cout << "found " << n << " at " << p << " " << m << "\n";
        } 
    }
}
...
...
```

This is really just the very basic idea.

Some hints what to think about:

- how do you want to handle repeated entries? (output once? you'll need to break or a flag)
- what if there is no such element in the 2D array? (want to say something like "elem not found"... again, a flag will be necessary.

I hope you can go on from here yourself.

Some ideas to improve your code:

- parametrize the '5'. Like `int d = 5`. Then use `d` to init the array and to break out of the for-loop.
- note that `k` is closely related to your `p`. Maybe you can always use `p`? I'll let you figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

A exampie of simple brute force implementation:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int f[5][5], k = 1, n;
    for (int p = 0; p<5; p++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Elements Of Rows: " << k << endl;
        k++;
        for (int m = 0; m<5; m++)
        {
            cin >> f[p][m];//It take's rows as input
        }
    }
    cout << "Enter the number you want to search:  ";
    cin >> n;
    vector<pair<int, int> > result;
    for (int p = 0; p<5; p++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m<5; m++)
        {
            if (n == f[p][m]) result.push_back(pair<int, int>(p, m));
        }
    }
    cout << "Search results:" << endl;
    for (std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << "[" << it->first << "][" << it->second << "]" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```